# Move email addresses to company domain

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, mailbox, organizational-unit

My current setup is Exchange 2010 and I have 4 different organisational units setup.  We have a number of users spread across these organisational units.  We would like to now move to a single domain/organisational unit lets call it *newcompany.com*.

What is the best approach to move all existing email addresses to the new single domain/organisational unit and also move existing mailbox items.

Also, once above is completed everyone should be able to login via OWA for the new domain/organisational unit i.e. *https://myexchange.newcompany.com/owa* so that need to be considered as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the domain newcompany.com as a new domain accepted and create a alias policy to apply to everyone.

That way old email alias will still work and the new's one too.

Be sure to switch the primary's when the user are ready for the switch.

2) For the OWA link you will need to change the Virtual directory to use that domain and you will have to create a new SSL certificate.

To see what is configured, and for setting the autodiscover:

Get-OWAVirtualDirectory -Server $Server

Get-ECPVirtualDirectory -Server $Server

Get-OABVirtualDirectory -Server $Server

Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory -Server $Server

Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Server $Server

Get-ClientAccessServer -Identity $server | Set-ClientAccessServer -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri https://autodiscover.newdomain.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

Comment: thanks for the info.

However, I want to eventually remove the old domain mailboxes if we migrate to a new server.  Your suggestion does not involve creating a new mailbox for the domain so I am not sure your suggestion covers that.

Should each user create a PST file of their mailbox and then import it again to the new mailbox.

Comment: @scotspines Hi, thanks for the clarification. New domain can be large as a term, and I didnt thought you were switching of server. No I didnt discuss that part, how much users ?

Comment: we have about 450 users.  Basically, I want to end up with all mailbox having a newcompany.com domain email address.  At the moment not everyone has a newcompany.com mailbox and that is what I want.  I can create a newcompany.com mailbox for each user that i need and then somehow migrate or move their mailbox items from other mailboxes to the new one.  I can then delete those older mailboxes and possibly add as alias their old email address to the newcompany.com mailbox.

Comment: just to clarify, newcompany.com already got a mail server? I ask as to give an example, one of my customer got 6 separated company hosted in its exchange

Comment: Yes the newcompany.com is already on a mail server.  In fact it is already setup as an organisational unit on our existing exchange server.

Comment: @scotspines you can't migrate the mailbox via exchange then ?

Comment: are you able to explain your comment?  Is it a question or a statement of fact?

Comment: @scotspines you install two exchange in the same active directory, those server are usually able to talk to each other, its a common migration path. What block you to migrate ?

Comment: as a test I used Active Directory Users and Computers to move a user to a new organisational unit.  Once done I was able to use the OWA for new organisational unit to login to the email account. So http://exchange101.newcompany.com/owa.  To login i had to use the email address of old company.  What i want to be able to do is use email address of newcompany.com to login to OWA.  As a further test i added the email address for newcompany.com to the user and marked it 'Set As Reply'  but i still can't use it to access http://exchange101.newcompany.com/owa.